# Translating Prolog code to Lisp

Tags: prolog, lisp, common-lisp

Prolog and Lisp are both considered languages for AI programming. What will be the Lisp equivalent of following Prolog code which searches for siblings based on given father-child relations:

```
father_child(tom, sally).
father_child(john, alfred).
father_child(george, peter).
father_child(tom, dick).
father_child(john, harry).
father_child(george, eliz).

siblings(X, Y):-  father_child(Z, X), father_child(Z, Y), X \= Y.   

?- siblings(harry,X).
X = alfred ;
```

Edit: The question is not too broad, rather very specific as to converting this particular code to Lisp. Hence, I it should be reopened.

Comment: Prolog is all about relations on sets.  Lisp has set functions as well.  One possible translation: http://paste.lisp.org/display/319881

Comment: The "too broad" reason means "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." The (short and useless) answer to your question is "write a prolog interpreter or compiler, use exactly the same code". Logic programming is sufficiently different that there's no obvious trivial way of making a quick code conversion.

Comment: Take a look at Kanren for some inspiration. Yet, the most idiomatic approach to do this in Lisp is to embed a Prolog eDSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lisp is a **functional** programming language (or rather, and imperative language with a pure functional subset), and so the **relational** programming that Prolog enables does not carry over to Lisp, at least not directly, because a function is only a *special case* of a relation and can be expressed easily, whereas expressing a relation in terms of functions is more involved.

Most notably, a function only works in *one direction*, and so you cannot expect to use Lisp directly to answer more general cases that are easily possible with Prolog.

Also, use **[prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)** instead of the less general `(\=)/2`. `father_child/2` is a good name for a relation, making clear what each argument is.

Prolog and Lisp are both considered languages for AI programming, much like both Bugatti and Ford are considered car manufacturers.

Comment: Can you write some Lisp code as example to the excellent points that you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

One usually uses for such an example an embedded relational / logic language in Lisp.

The example uses KnowledgeWorks, an extension of LispWorks, which provides a version of Prolog in Lisp:

```
(require "prolog")

(in-package "CP-USER")

(clog:defrel father-child
  ((father-child tom    sally))
  ((father-child john   alfred))
  ((father-child george peter))
  ((father-child tom    dick))
  ((father-child john   harry))
  ((father-child george eliz)))


(clog:defrel siblings
 ((siblings ?x ?y)
  (and (father-child ?z ?x)
       (father-child ?z ?y)
       (/== ?x ?y))))
```

Let's try it:

```
CP-USER 35 > (clog:logic '(siblings harry ?x))
(SIBLINGS HARRY ALFRED)
T
```

Comment: Great. But this is essentially using Prolog code. I want to use common-lisp for same problem.

Comment: @mso: then you should try to write it. Stackoverflow is not a code writing bot. Stackoverflow is best for actual programming questions, where you post the code. The code from my example is Common Lisp code. Embedding languages in Lisp is common.

Comment: I have currently no experience in Lisp. I suspect that in Lisp it will have to be usual iterative code rather than automatic implied iteration of Prolog. With your experience, you are obviously one of the best person to comment on this.